# Using 'property' as the name of a method in a python class

Tags: python, properties, scope, decorator, naming

Is this possible in Python?

```
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def property(self):
        return self._property
```

That is, I want to have a property named 'property'. It actually runs fine, but Eclipse complains with a warning. I thought the built-in @property decorator lived in a different namespace than the methods and properties within my classes.

Is it possible to rename the built-in decorator within the scope of the relevant module, so I can use the name 'property' without receiving this warning? Maybe something like the following:

```
attr = property

class MyClass(object):
    @attr
    def property(self):
        return self._property
```

I do this, but I still get the warning, since I created an alias for the global built-in @property decorator, but the name 'property' is still a valid way to refer to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with naming a property `property` is the following:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def property(self):
        return "ham"

    @property
    def other_property(self):
        return "spam"
```

The second property can't be defined since you've shadowed the name `property` in the class definition.

You can get around this by "renaming" `property` as in your example, but if I were you, I wouldn't mess with the built-ins in this way. It makes your code harder to follow.

Comment: It can be defined, just not like that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: yes, the OP's workaround would do the trick. Added that to the answer.

Comment: @larsmans, I already noticed your problem and I solved it by declaring  my "def property" as the last property in the class. It actually does the trick and it runs. It's just eclipse's warning that bothers me. It doesn't even warns me when I run the script.

Comment: @Ernesto: I don't use Eclipse, so I can't tell you how to turn off the warning. I'd just advise you not to call a property `property`, but it's your call and it is safe from the pov of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are ordinary functions, so they live in the same namespace as other functions. Indeed your `property` function is inside class `Foo`; but it turns out that that's where python first looks for decorator names, so there's a conflict.

You can see this from the fact that the following code compiles:

```
class Foo(object):

    def decfun(x): return "ham"

    @decfun
    def second(self, y): pass
```